# c# datagrid checkbox multi delete

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagrid

I have problem when I delete multichecked rows with this button. It only delete first row. 
cell_dellklient is the name of checkbox in dataGridView1
yes is the true value of checkbox

Please help

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        con.Open();

        object cell = row.Cells["cell_delklient"].Value;
        if (cell == "yes")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Klienci where Nazwa ='" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            wyczytywaniegridu();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening the connection once on each iteration and closing it twice on each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
  public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
        string nazwa = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[row.Index].ToString();
       //Check if checkbox is checked.
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))
       {
            string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someConString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Klienci where Nazwa=@Nazwa", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nazwa", nazwa);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry but Im beginier. I tried this but im receiving:'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataKeys' and no extension method 'DataKeys' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Im using windows forms in visual studio 2015.

Comment: I receive the same error for FindControl like i did for DataKeys:(

Comment: That information was for ASP.NET.  I just made some modification on the code to match WinForm.

Answer (score 0):

iam also new, i have met this situation also. i think you need to loop it. i once use this code and also iam using devexpress. so i dont quiet sure about datagridview. try to get the logic from here :D

**This is not an answer**

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

            bool x = Convert.ToBoolean(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["check"]);
            if (x == true)
            {                   
                   delete_data();                                      
            }
        }
```